# Office JS RoamingSettings interface not working properly

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I noticed a weird behavior of the roaming settings in Office JS for an outlook add in. The add in has two buttons and their actions are declared in the manifest.xml like this:

```
<OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
  <Group id="apptComposeGroup">
    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="loginButton"\>
      ...
      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">      
        <FunctionName>login</FunctionName>    
      </Action>  
    <Control>  
    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="logoutButton"\>
      ...  
      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">      
        <FunctionName>logout</FunctionName>    
     </Action>  
    <Control>
  </Group>
</OfficeTab>
```

In commands.ts I have the following code:

```
async function login(event){
  console.log('1', Office.context.roamingSettings.get('foo'));
  Office.context.roamingSettings.set('foo', 'bar')
  Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync();
  console.log('2', Office.context.roamingSettings.get('foo'));
  event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
}

async function logout(event){
  console.log('3', Office.context.roamingSettings.get('foo'));
  Office.context.roamingSettings.remove('foo')
  Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync();
  console.log('4', Office.context.roamingSettings.get('foo'));
  event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
}

Office.actions.associate(login.name, login);
Office.actions.associate(logout.name, logout);
```

What happens here if I click the following sequence: login, logout, login:

```
1 undefined
2 bar
3 undefined 
4 undefined
1 bar 
2 bar
```

It looks like the roaming settings are independent for each method, which is weird since the settings are stored at the mailbox level and I should be able to access the same settings from different contexts. Does anyone have an idea of why is behaving like this?